# Processing the array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, logic

I have an array of objects. I have to somehow process this data and create an HTML document. I have no problems with HTML and CSS, but don't know where to start with JS and how to process the data. I don't even understand how to describe my problem correctly in order to Google some similar solutions. Can anyone help me to make a plan what exactly I should do?

I've made a picture describing the logic. When users click the button, they'll see a menu (in a block looks like a dropdown menu), then they can go through category and select the item they want to choose. Please note that there's only one block, in the pic I'm just showing the logic. After that, below the user can see the list of items they selected

```js
const menu = [{
  categories: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Desserts',
    categories: [{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Ice cream',
      categories: [{
        id: 3,
        name: 'Vanilla',
        categories: []
      }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Strawberry',
        categories: []
      }]
    }, {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Baked apples',
      categories: []
    }]
  }, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Coffee',
    categories: []
  }, {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Tea',
    categories: [{
      id: 8,
      name: 'Green tea',
      categories: [{
        id: 9,
        name: 'With Jasmine',
        categories: []
      }, {
        id: 10,
        name: 'Simple',
        categories: []
      }]
    }, {
      id: 11,
      name: 'Black Tea',
      categories: []
    }]
  }]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: You just need a loop. What should the final HTML output look like?

Comment: I think second list should show `Baked apples` too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan like I've shown in the white box in the bottom of the picture - the category name, then the sub-category if it exists, then the item (Desserts -> Ice Cream -> Vanilla). Pretty simple

Comment: @GrafiCode oh yeah, you're right. Just missed them

Comment: Well yes, but is your HTML in `ul`/`li` or divs, or some other construct. There's a million ways you could 'simply' do this, hence why I asked.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thought about ul/li structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I show you the one of sample logic. You can add more looping and styles as per the level of categories and requirements you have;

```
var objData= JSON.parse(aResultData);
var sHtml  = '<ul>';

for(var i=0; i<objData.length; i++) {
 sHtml = sHtml + '<li>'+objData[i].name+'</li>';

 if (objData[i].categories.length>0) {
  for(var j=0; j<objData[i].categories.length; j++) {
   if (j==0) {
    sHtml = sHtml + '<ul>'+objData[j].name+'</ul>';
   } else {
    sHtml = sHtml + '<li>'+objData[j].name+'</li>';
   }
   if (objData[j].categories.length>0) {
    for(var k=0; k<objData[j].categories.length; k++) {
     if (k==0) {
      sHtml = sHtml + '<ul>'+objData[k].name+'</ul>';
     } else {
      sHtml = sHtml + '<li>'+objData[k].name+'</li>';
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
sHtml = sHtml + '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In this approach, I first flatten your object structure assigning each item a reference to its parent's ID.

The array structured this way easily allows you to `filter` "subitems".

```js
const menu = [{
  categories: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Desserts',
    categories: [{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Ice cream',
      categories: [{
        id: 3,
        name: 'Vanilla',
        categories: []
      }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Strawberry',
        categories: []
      }]
    }, {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Baked apples',
      categories: []
    }]
  }, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Coffee',
    categories: []
  }, {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Tea',
    categories: [{
      id: 8,
      name: 'Green tea',
      categories: [{
        id: 9,
        name: 'With Jasmine',
        categories: []
      }, {
        id: 10,
        name: 'Simple',
        categories: []
      }]
    }, {
      id: 11,
      name: 'Black Tea',
      categories: []
    }]
  }]
}]



const m = menu[0].categories


// THIS WILL BE THE FLAT ARRAY OF ITEMS IN MENU
let arr = []


// ITERATE ROOT CATEGORIES
for (let cat of m) {
  // FOR EACH CATEGORY, CALL THE RECURSIVE FUNCTION
  recurCats(cat, 0)
}


// HERE IS THE FLAT ARRAY
console.log(arr)


const level0 = arr.filter(item => item.parentID == 0).map(item => '<option data-id="' + item.id + '" value="' + item.name + '">' + item.name + '</option>')

document.getElementById('s1').innerHTML = '<option value="0">Select an item</option>' + level0.join('')


document.getElementById('s1').addEventListener('change', function() {
  let thisID = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id')

  const level1 = arr.filter(item => item.parentID == thisID).map(item => '<option data-id="' + item.id + '" value="' + item.name + '">' + item.name + '</option>')

  document.getElementById('s2').innerHTML = '<option value="0">Select an item</option>' + level1.join('')

})


document.getElementById('s2').addEventListener('change', function() {
  let thisID = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id')

  const level2 = arr.filter(item => item.parentID == thisID).map(item => '<option data-id="' + item.id + '" value="' + item.name + '">' + item.name + '</option>')

  document.getElementById('s3').innerHTML = '<option value="0">Select an item</option>' + level2.join('')

})


// RECURSIVE FUNCTION
function recurCats(cat, parentID) {
  arr.push({
    name: cat.name,
    id: cat.id,
    parentID: parentID
  })

  if (cat.hasOwnProperty('categories') && cat.categories.length > 0) {
    for (let subcat of cat.categories) {
      recurCats(subcat, cat.id)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="s1"></select>

<select id="s2"></select>

<select id="s3"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

first step : change jo object to HTML UL / LI

recursive method=

```js
const menu = 
  [ {                                           categories: 
      [ { id: 1,          name: 'Desserts',     categories: 
          [ { id: 2,      name: 'Ice cream',    categories: 
              [ { id: 3,  name: 'Vanilla',      categories: [] } 
              , { id: 4,  name: 'Strawberry',   categories: [] } 
            ] } 
          , { id: 5,      name: 'Baked apples', categories: [] } 
        ] } 
      , { id: 6,          name: 'Coffee',       categories: [] } 
      , { id: 7,          name: 'Tea',          categories: 
          [ { id: 8,      name: 'Green tea',    categories: 
            [ { id: 9,    name: 'With Jasmine', categories: [] } 
            , { id: 10,   name: 'Simple',       categories: [] } 
            ] } 
          , { id: 11,     name: 'Black Tea',    categories: [] } 
  ] } ] } ] 
     
let menuEl = document.querySelector('nav')

addElements( menuEl, menu[0].categories )

function addElements(parent, arr)   // UL /LI buider
  {
  let ul = parent.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'))
  arr.forEach(el => 
    {
    let li = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
    li.dataset.id  = el.id
    li.textContent = el.name
    if (el.categories.length > 0) addElements(li, el.categories)
    })
  }
```

```css
  nav ul
    {
    list-style: none;
    }
```

```html
<nav></nav>
```

second step: make some CSS choices for presentations...